# How to use CSS on multiple buttons created by loop MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created multiple buttons by looping one set of button tags in ASP.NET MVC Razor. How do I use CSS to change the background color on the one button that is active when I click one of the buttons that is automatically populated?

I have checked the Id of all the buttons come up with the same Id and I don't know how to give them their own Id, because they are generated buttons.

View:

[image]

```
                @{ int firstRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + 1;
                int lastRecord = (webGrid.PageIndex * webGrid.RowsPerPage) + webGrid.Rows.Count();
            }
            <div id="RowCountTop"><b>Records: @firstRecord - @lastRecord of @webGrid.TotalRowCount</b></div>

            <br />
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "formYardDog" }))
            {
                //Loop to Get Dictionary List Buttons with Distinct Section Values.
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Section.Count; i++)
                {

                    <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" value=@Model.Section[i].Value id="ddlSectionButtons" , new { onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" class="ddlSectionButtons" onClick="focusMe(this);" } />

                }
                <!-- All Sections Button for PlantLocation -->
                <button text="All" value=" " type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.Section)" , new { onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" onClick="focusMe(this);" id="ddlSectionAllButton" class="ddlSectionButtons" placeholder="All" hidden="hidden" })>All</button>

                <!-- No need for Second Section Drop-Down Box -->
                //Html.LabelFor(model => model.Section, "All", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", id = "ddlSectionAllButtonLbl", Class ="ddlSectionButtons", placeholder = "All" })


                //Testing button selection (Below):
                //@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Section, new { Class = "name", placeholder="All", type="submit", value=" " })

            }

            <br /> <br />
            <button class="YardDogAdminButton" onclick="location.href='/YardDogAdmin/YardDogAdmin'" type="button" target="_blank">Admin Page</button>
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Section, Model.Section, "Section", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlSection", @class = "ddlSection" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlantLocation, Model.PlantLocation, "PlantLocation", new { onchange = "document.forms[0].submit();", @id = "ddlWarehouses", @class = "ddlWarehouses" })
            <br /><br />

            <hr />
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
    //List Section Buttons handler.
  $("body").on("click", ".ddlSectionButtons", function () {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
  $('#formYardDog')[0].submit().is(this).children('.ddlSectionButtons').focus();

   //$(this).children('.ddlSectionButtons').css('background-color', '#AFE1AF').focus();

 });
```

Controller:

```
    //Population Controller. 
    public static YardDogModel PopulateModel(string country, string city)
    {
        using (PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3 entities = new PW_YardDogDataEntitiesModel3())
        {
            YardDogModel model = new YardDogModel()
            {
                LocationDatas = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where c.PlantLocation == country && c.Section == city && c.Section == c.Section && c.Location == c.Location && c.PlantLocation == country || string.IsNullOrEmpty(country) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(city) && c.PlantLocation == country
                                 select c).ToList(),

                LocationList = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Location) && c.Location != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && country == c.PlantLocation //  && country == c.PlantLocation// && townList == c.Location // && city == c.Section && country == c.PlantLocation
                                select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Location, Value = c.Location }).Distinct().ToList(),

                SectionList = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                               where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                               select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),


                Section = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                           where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation
                           select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Section, Value = c.Section }).Distinct().ToList(),


                PlantLocation = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                 where (c.PlantLocation == c.PlantLocation)
                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = c.PlantLocation, Value = c.PlantLocation }).Distinct().ToList(),

                LocationAppended = (from c in entities.LocationDatas
                                    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Section) && c.Section != null && country == c.PlantLocation && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.TrailerNumber)
                                    select new SelectListItem { Text =  c.Section + " " + c.Location + " " + c.LocationID, Value = c.Section + " " + c.Location + " " + c.LocationID }).Distinct().ToList(),
                //LocationAppendedLbl = LocationAppended,
            };
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put the beginform inside the loop instead. that should work.

Comment: I tried this and still get the same result, but thank you anyways!... Maybe you can show me how it should look?... Not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I create an example but I am using Javascript only

the controller

```
 public ActionResult TesttButton() {

            List<TestBtn> TS = new List<TestBtn>();

            TestBtn TS1 = new TestBtn
            {
                Id = 1,
                Description = "Test1"
            };

            TS.Add(TS1);

            TestBtn TS2 = new TestBtn
            {
                Id = 2,
                Description = "Test2"
            };

            TS.Add(TS2);

            return View(TS);
        }
```

The View

```
     @model IEnumerable<TestButton.Models.TestBtn>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TesttButton";
}

<h2>TesttButton</h2>

<table class="table table-responsive">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" Id="button_@i"  onclick="changeColor(@i)" />
            </td>
            <td>
                TEST1
            </td>

        </tr>
       
    }


</table>


@section Scripts{ 


    <script>
        function changeColor(i) {

            var btnname = "button_" + i

            alert(btnname);

            document.getElementById(btnname).style.background = '#000000';
        }

      </script>

     }
```

you may set the background color to whatever you want on the scripts.